# Confused on the grammar for asking people to do something

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

I've wondered how to ask people to do you a favour without making a grammatical or implicational screw-up.

For example, I've considered these sentences:

> Can you pass the ketchup, please?

(Meaning: Are you able to pass the ketchup?)

> May you pass the ketchup, please?

(Meaning: Do you have permission to pass the ketchup?)

The following sentences might make sense, but seem a bit rude.

> Will you pass the ketchup, please?
>
> Pass the ketchup, please.

What makes sense when you ask someone to do something simple?

Comment: Whoa, you're taking the meaning of "can" **too literally**! The point is, it's the normal structure for requesting something- even if it's rudimentarily simple. I don't get where your confusion about "will" comes, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things you can say to get some ketchup handed to you:

1: Can you pass the ketchup, please? (Note: do not use with english teachers, as they may say, "I can, yes," and then fail to do so until you use a different phrase. Nearly everyone *else* will just hand you the ketchup, though.)

2: Will you pass the ketchup, please? (Note: use tone and body-language to indicate you are not upset, and make sure your "thanks" is cheerful. This phrasing *can* be used in an angry way, so it's not as good as...)

3: Could you pass me the ketchup, please?

4: Would you pass me the ketchup, please?

5: Pass [me] the ketchup, please? (Note: this is not rude at all, unless you are saying it in an angry fashion. The "please?" at the end makes it okay.)

5a: Please pass the ketchup. (Note: again, tone of voice is key; so long as you aren't saying it with exasperation, and add a "thanks!" when you get it, you're fine.)

6: Could I get some ketchup over here, please? (Note: again, tone of voice distinguishes between grouchy and "hey, need some ketchup here! Thanks!")

7: My kingdom for the ketchup, woe, woe! (Note: use only with people who appreciate melodrama, and make sure to have the back of your hand to your forehead as you declaim.)

EDITED TO ADD: 8. As Codeswitcher notes in the comments, "Might you pass me the ketchup?" is also acceptable, and in American, probably doesn't need a "please" (though you can certainly add one!). It would tend to be seen as formal/British, and therefore "polite by definition" if the body-language and tone of voice were not hostile.

Don't use "May you pass the ketchup" under any normal circumstances.

Comment: Then under what circumstances should I use "May you pass the ketchup?"

Comment: If there is some question as to whether the person has permission to touch the ketchup bottle. Which is theoretically possible, I suppose, like if they have a religious prohibition against tomatoes, or if they're a kid who isn't allowed to touch the fancy container for the home-made ketchup. But if you ever find yourself in such circumstances, I will be *very* surprised.

Comment: I immediately had a hostage scenario in mind for "May you pass...", but I've been watching NCIS lately ;-)

Comment: THE KETCHUP SHALL NOT PASS! Ahem. Sorry, too much *Lord of the Rings*...

Comment: You missed the unusual but legit (and maybe confusing @Pyraminx?) "Might you pass me the ketchup?"  Sounds like "May you...", but "may you..." is essentially never correct.

Comment: That's true, I did. I believe that form, "Might you pass me the ketchup?", is more British than American, which means it doesn't even really need the "please" in the American dialects I'm familiar with. It's already "British" and therefore by definition "Extremely Polite and Proper."

Comment: To my (American) ear, "Please pass the ketchup" sounds the most natural.  This is partly based on context -- "Please pass the <item(s)>" is normal as part of passing food, dishes, and flatware around a dining table.  Some of the other choices are more natural in non-dining contexts.